# action method not fired in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a controller like bellow

```
public class MenuController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Menu/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public RedirectResult logout()
        {
            return RedirectPermanent("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

and I set a break-point on **logout** for first time if I hit URL in address-bar localhost:(port number)/menu/logout code stop at breakpoint as expected but after that each and time code not stop breakpoint.

I spend around 2-3 hours and found some stack overflow link where some body write clear browser cache I do that and its working but only once ,that means I have to clear cache each time before debug .I use fire-fox(50.1.0) .try above code to replicate .please help I am stuck badly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `RedirectPermanent()` *does*.  It basically tells the browser, "This resource will *never* be working again, so always request this redirected URL instead."  So the browser remembers that and doesn't bother requesting a resource that it's been told will never work again.

If you want the redirect to be temporary, don't make it permanent:

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks ,Redirect() working fine ,I also found a link https://wpscholar.com/blog/browser-caching-301-redirects/ which is very informative and helpful for knowledge .

Answer (score 1):

Because you're calling `RedirectPermanent`

Your browser is (correctly) caching the fact that visiting `/logout` **permanently** redirects to *(in this case)* Google.
It's performing a 301 redirect.

Use `Redirect` instead

```
public RedirectResult logout()
{
    return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```